# Codeigniter url rewrite issue when using pagination

Tags: pagination, codeigniter-url

I am learning codeigniter these days. I have done a website for my own use a couple of days ago where i have just applied pagination today but it seems there is problem with my url rewriting.

```
Here is my action inside my controller which grabs list of authors in a category
    `public function index() {
         $data['main_content'] = "templates/public/audio/author_view";
         $data['authors'] = $this->author_model->get_authors();
         $this->load->view("templates/public/template",$data);
     }`
```

```
Here is my function that grabs value from db located inside my author model
      `public function get_authors($type = 0) {
        $this->db->select("author.name,author.image,author.slug");
        $this->db->from("author");
        $this->db->join("album","author.id = album.author_id");
        $this->db->where("album.mime_type",$type);
        $this->db->group_by("author.name");
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }`
```

When i clicked on one of author grabbed it open all albums of selected author. then url looks link www.xyz.com/audio/album-name
Here is my code for this route.

```
$route['audio/(:any)'] = "audio/view_author_album";
```

At this stage it works fine. But now today when i applied pagination i found that this route will not do more work for me. I have added pagination in my index action Below you can see my code

```
    public function index() {
        $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/mywebsite/audio/index/";
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->author_model->get_total_rows();
        $config['per_page'] = 1;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['main_content'] = "templates/public/audio/author_view";
        $data['authors'] = $this->author_model->get_authors($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view("templates/public/template",$data);
    }
```

This open the details http://localhost/mysite/audio/index/2

against this url my route rule $route['audio/(:any)/(:any)'] = "audio/view_album_details"; works.
 It should grab the next page instead of my detail view. 
 And url should be something like http://localhost/mysite/audio/2 
I also tried $route['audio/(:num)'] = "audio/;

I will highly appropriate if anyone can help me in solving this problem.

Answer (score -1):

i encounter the same issue and i solve it by using two same router

$route['a-b-c/([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]*)'] = "product/category/$1";
$route['a-b-c/([a-z0-9-]+)'] = "product/category/";

Comment: Could you explain your solution?